# multigpu alexnet googlenet tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am looking for a multigpu off-the-shelf algorithms for alexnet and googlenet in tensorflow with my data. I find many benchmark codes such as convnet bench, http://www.comp.hkbu.edu.hk/%E2%88%BCchxw/dlbench.html[1]. But nothing satisifies my above need. For eg., in the case of caffe, I simply run

`caffe train --solver=googlenet.prototxt --gpu=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7`

Similarly in the case of CNTK, I run

`mpiexec -n <#workers> python AlexNet_ImageNet_Distributed.py -datadir myimages/`

MXNet also provides easier interfaces to run alexnet and googlenet.

I also looked at slim for tensorflow

```
DATASET_DIR=/tmp/imagenet
TRAIN_DIR=/tmp/train_logs
python train_image_classifier.py \
    --train_dir=${TRAIN_DIR} \
    --dataset_name=imagenet \
    --dataset_split_name=train \
    --dataset_dir=${DATASET_DIR} \
    --model_name=inception_v3
```

But it is not clear what to change in model_deploy to define using multi gpu's.

However, in tensorflow I could not find anything off-the-shelf that just takes the number of gpu's to run and the image path to train in multiple gpu's. Is there any off-the-shelf python/c++ code that I can use or do I need to build one myself by extending the cifar_10_multi_gpu example from tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to set your GPU devices by `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1,2,3,...`